# request.security issue in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hi i want to get RSI value using request.security but when i query previous value which is RSI[1]

it return random value .

if i don't use request.security it return correct RSI value but to get RSI[1] value if use

request.security it return some weird random value.

if anyone help me how to get correct RSI[1] value using request.security?

thanks

```
rsi  = ta.rsi(close, rsi_length)
rsi1 = ta.rsi(close, 11)[1]
rsiprev = request.security(sym, timeframe.period, rsi1)
rsi_cond = rsi < 50 and rsiprev > 20 and rsiprev < 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
rsi  = ta.rsi(close, rsi_length)

rsiprev = request.security(sym, timeframe.period, rsi[1])
rsi_cond = rsi < 50 and rsiprev > 20 and rsiprev < 50
```